# Replace SDK classes with classes from JAR in my app

Tags: java, android, classloader

I need to use json.org from jar file from libs folder in my project instead of Android sdk json.org classes.

I have set up Eclipse and now it prefer json.org classes from jar instead of Android sdk. But when I run my app on device it use sdk json.org classes.

I think, that I can load json.org classes from jar manually using custom class loader.

It is possible to do? Or may be exists any other way to use classes from lib instead of sdk classes?

Comment: Why do you need to load classes from a jar? What is wrong with the SDK classes? If the classes you want to load do something different they should be renamed. Is there some other issue?

Comment: Clyde, SDK json.org is too old. I need new version.

Comment: Have a look at jackson -  http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome. It is much better than json.org.

Comment: Clyde, I know that exists alternatives to json.org, but I use it because it fully cover my needs

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to use specific jar instead  of the existing in android SDK, you can set up priorities in eclipse (right click -> build path) and then specify the priority.
2. If you want to load a jar in the class loader, it's also possible, you can use the class URL

> URLClassLoader jsonUrl = new URLClassLoader (jsonJar.toURL(), this.getClass().getClassLoader()); 
>   Class classToLoad = Class.forName ("com.MyClass", true, jsonUrl); 
>   Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod ("myMethod"); 
>   Object instance = classToLoad.newInstance (); Object result = method.invoke (instance);

Comment: I have made 1, but device still use SDK classes instead of JAR classes.

Comment: Like Clyde says, normally two classes can't be in the same package, the second normally should be named differently. But any way, try to do the second one.

Comment: Bouhanef, I have not path to jar. I place it inside libs folder and it compiled to apk file. I think, this will works for jars in file system only.